# How could I extract all the numbers from a data frame into a vector?

Tags: r

Now I have a table of number which may have duplicated ones and NA. I want to extract all the numbers into a single vector and remove all the NA

How should I do that?

Now I'm considering doing it column by column, (gt1 is my table and FGT is the first column)

```
as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(gt1$FGT, "\\d")))
```

I want to get c(35, 20, 28...
However, the result of it is that it extracts all the digits, which is c(3, 5, 2, 0, 2, 8, ...

Comment: `"\\d+"` to select one or more digits. Are your columns strings that you want to extract digits from? Or are they already numeric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract all the elements with

```r
x = unlist(gt1,use.names=FALSE)
```

Making them numeric with

```r
x = as.numeric(x)
```

Now you may remove NAs and duplicates via

```r
x = x[!is.na(x)]
x = unique(x)
```